# Error upon building in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Just wanna ask if any of you experience build error in visual studio 2012 that points in this line of code:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
```

I have both 2010 and 2012 version of visual studio in my computer and previously open the app in the 2010 what are the action to be taken in order to build my application successfully.

Comment: Specifically, which of those 3 lines is the error and what is the error message?

Comment: Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.


but the target file on 11.0 and 10.0 is there